# catkin_make ignores INCLUDE_DIRS directive in catkin_generate_package

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having a problem with catkin_make ignoring an include directory directive. The only way for catkin_make to 'see' it is to use the `include_directories(src/include)` directive. For some reason the `INCLUDE_DIRS` directive in `catkin_package` works in another project of mine just fine, but not in this project. It also has the unpleasant side effect of rebuilding all other projects when `include_directories` is first used, which is not pleasant if you have RViz in your catkin_make source tree.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file I am using. There are probably a few unneeded dependencies as this file is derived from another project. I still have not got my head around the intracacies of CMake and its interactoins with catkin_make and ROS.

```
# Instructions from
# wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt
#
# 1. Required CMake Version (cmake_minimum_required)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

# 2. Package Name (project())
project(can_bus_read)

# 3. Find other CMake/Catkin packages needed for build (find_package())
find_package(catkin REQUIRED nodelet roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation sensor_msgs)
find_package(roscpp REQUIRED)

# 4. Message/Service/Action Generators (add_message_files(), add_service_files(), add_action_files())
add_message_files(
   FILES
   canbus_raw.msg
)

# 5. Invoke message/service/action generation (generate_messages())
catkin_python_setup()
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs)

# 6. Specify package build info export (catkin_package())
catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS src/include
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
   DEPENDS)

# 7. Libraries/Executables to build (add_library()/add_executable()/target_link_libraries())
include_directories(src/include)

add_executable(candump src/candump.c
 src/lib.c
 src/lib.h
 src/terminal.h
 src/include/linux/can.h
 src/include/linux/can/bcm.h
 src/include/linux/can/error.h
 src/include/linux/can/gw.h
 src/include/linux/can/isotp.h
 src/include/linux/can/netlink.h
 src/include/linux/can/raw.h
 )

target_link_libraries(candump ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_definitions(-D_LINUX -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DUSE_INTTYPES__ -DHAVE_PCAP -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN)

# 8. Tests to build (catkin_add_gtest())

# 9. Install rules (install()) 

#### END OF FILE #####
`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171261/catkin_make-ignores-include_dirs-directive-in-catkin_generate_package/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `INCLUDE_DIRS` directive to `catkin_package` is not intended to add include directories to your package; you should use `include_directories` for that, as you've found.

The `catkin_package` function specifies which dependencies your package exports to its dependencies. In particular, `INCLUDE_DIRS` specifies which directory in your package contains the header directory that should be on the include path for any packages that compile against your package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-05-28**:
Hmmm, the mystery deepens. I will have to find out why my other project has always worked without the `include_directories` directive, despite it having a very similar scenario of having project specific include files in a subdirectory of the code.